# swift firebase like button

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In tableViewCell I have likeButton and unlikeButton. What I want is when I press the likeButton - save data from cell to firebase and when unlike - delete

But I have 2 problems:

1-- when I click likeButton in `cell == indexPath.row 0 or 1` for example likeButton is clicked on the last or previous cell

2-- when I click unlikeButton I want to remove - but this does not work

In cell I have:

```
var index: Int?
var cat = ""
var quoteNAme = ""
var quoteNum = ""

  @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         sender.tag = index!
        saveToUser(whereSave: "userLikes", quant: "quantLikes")

        self.likeBtn.isEnabled = false

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Цитаты").child("\(cat)").child("\(quoteNAme)").child("\(quoteNum)")
        let keyToPost = ref.childByAutoId().key!
        let updateLikes: [String : Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
        ref.updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in
            if error == nil {
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                    if let properties = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        if let likes = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            let count = likes.count
                            self.likeLabel.text = "\(count)"
                            let update = ["quant" : count]
                            ref.updateChildValues(update)
                            self.likeBtn.isHidden = true
                            self.unlikeBtn.isHidden = false
                            self.likeBtn.isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
          ref.removeAllObservers()
        }
    }

@IBAction func unlikePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.unlikeBtn.isEnabled = false
        deleFromUser(whereSave: "userLikes", quant: "quantLikes")

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Цитаты").child("\(cat)").child("\(quoteNAme)").child("\(quoteNum)")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let properties = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let peopleWhoLike = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    for (id,person) in peopleWhoLike {
                        if person as? String == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                            ref.child("peopleWhoLike").child(id).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reff) in
                                if error == nil {
                                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                                        if let prop = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                            if let likes = prop["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                                let count = likes.count
                                                self.likeLabel.text = "\(count)"
                                                ref.updateChildValues(["quant" : count])
                                            }else {
                                                self.likeLabel.text = "0"
                                                ref.updateChildValues(["quant" : 0])
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })

                            self.likeBtn.isHidden = false
                            self.unlikeBtn.isHidden = true
                            self.unlikeBtn.isEnabled = true
                            break

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
```

functions to save and remome

```
func saveToUser(whereSave:String, quant: String) {
        let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(userUID)")

        let keyToPost = ref.childByAutoId().key!
        let mark = "Цитаты/\(cat)/\(quoteNAme)/\(quoteNum)"
        let updateuser: [String : Any] = ["\(whereSave)/\(keyToPost)" : mark]
        ref.updateChildValues(updateuser, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in
            if error == nil {
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                    if let properties = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        if let likes = properties["\(whereSave)"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            let count = likes.count
                            let update = ["\(quant)" : count]
                            ref.updateChildValues(update)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func deleFromUser(whereSave:String, quant: String){
        let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let mark = "Цитаты/\(cat)/\(quoteNAme)/\(quoteNum)"
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(userUID)")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let properties = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let peopleWhoLike = properties["\(whereSave)"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    print("peopleWhoLike= \(peopleWhoLike)")
                    for (id,person) in peopleWhoLike {
                        if person as! String == mark {
                            ref.child("\(whereSave)").child(id).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reff) in
                                if error == nil {
                                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                                        if let prop = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                            print("prop=\(prop)")
                                            if let likes = prop["\(whereSave)"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                                let count = likes.count
                                                ref.updateChildValues(["\(quant)" : count])
                                            }else {
                                                ref.updateChildValues(["\(quant)" : 0])
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
```

In ViewController I have :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryQuoteCell") as! CategoryQuoteCell
    let tett = indexPath.row
    let quant = quantLike[tett]
    cell.quoteNAme = quoteNAme
    cell.quoteNum = quotenumber[indexPath.row]
    cell.cat = cat
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    cell.likeLabel.text = quant.description
    cell.quoteTF.text = quoteList[tett]

    cell.cellDelegate = self

    for person in self.posts[indexPath.row].peopleWhoLike {
        if person == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {

            cell.likeBtn.isHidden = true
            cell.unlikeBtn.isHidden = false

            break

        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

When press like btn -it' work good and save

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not doing something properly, when you press like you should pass the control to the Controller, not doing everything in tableViewCell. And also you're getting the previous index, because you're getting the index after the cell being touched. So I would suggest changing some pieces of code. On your tableViewCell

```
var onLikeTap: ((paramsThatYouWantToPass) -> Void)?
var onUnlikeTap: ((paramsThatYouWantToPass) -> Void)?
```

In your table view cell in like unlike actions:

```
@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     self.onLikeTap?(params)
}
```

Same for unlike

```
@IBAction func unlikePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.onUnlikeTap?(params)
}
```

Then on your Table View on `cellForRowAt` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryQuoteCell") as! CategoryQuoteCell
    cell.onLikeButton = { [weak self] (params) in 
       // your like function that you used previously
    }
     cell.onUnlikeButton = { [weak self] (params) in 
       // your unlike function that you used previously
    }
    // other cell configuration that you used before
    return cell
}
```

Also if you don't want to pass params to the like and unlike closures you can leave it without params

Comment: the same thing happens

Comment: In cellForRowAt use indexPath.row and not index